# Showing that $\sigma_A (a) = \sigma_C (A).$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, spectra

> Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $C$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra containing the identity of $A,$ and let $a$ be a self-adjoint element in $C.$ Then $\sigma_A (a) = \sigma_C (a).$

It's quite clear that $\sigma_A (a) \subseteq \sigma_C (a).$ Now suppose $\lambda \in \sigma_C (a).$ This implies that $\lambda - a$ has no inverse in $C.$ From here how do I conclude that it has no inverse in $A$ as well? Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This is a hard result in general. Is this an exercise, and if so in what book? Because most books would consider this as a theorem that is proven in the main text.

Comment: @QuantumSpace$:$ this is given as an exercise to the lecture notes in operator algebra given by our instructor. I am finally able to prove this with the help of Stone-Weierstrass theorem.